# ODATA - how to generate odata service from Edmx file

Tags: odata

There is some Odata lib which I can use that from **edmx file** it generate an
odata service? 
By providing only edmx file it create the service that can answer the metadata calls...

I've found this library

https://github.com/htammen/n-odata-server

But it requires json not edmx/metadata.xml file...

I see the Olingo lib but I didn't find any functionality that can do it ...

https://olingo.apache.org

Any direction if it possible?

I prefer to use some nodejs lib if there is some combination that could work, but its not mandatory

I've also find this lib
https://github.com/jaystack/jaysvcutil

Comment: which version of OData are you targetting 2 or 4?

Comment: @Shiva - V2 or V4 will be great...

Answer (score 0):

If you are happy to use .Net, you could try RESTier. Follow the instructions here: http://odata.github.io/RESTier/, except don't generate a new EF data model class. Instead add your edmx model into the project.

Then go to the section 'Configure the OData Endpoint', and rather than entering:

```
        await config.MapRestierRoute<EntityFrameworkApi<AdventureWorksLT>>(
            "AdventureWorksLT",
            "api/AdventureWorksLT",
            new RestierBatchHandler(GlobalConfiguration.DefaultServer));
```

use your data model class (the class that inherits DbContext) rather than AdventureWorksLT in 
`EntityFrameworkApi<AdventureWorksLT>`
 , and change the route name and prefix to something more suitable.

Comment: Sorry I cannot use .net , just java or node.js , there is someting similar ?

Comment: Ah sorry - because you were starting with an edmx file thought the .Net route would be available to you. The following seems to be Java specific though: http://aphethean.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/create-odata-service-from-edmx.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a maven plugin from SAP:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.sap.cloud.sdk.datamodel</groupId>
                <artifactId>odata-generator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.52.0</version>
                ...
```

See documentation here https://sap.github.io/cloud-sdk/docs/java/features/odata/generate-typed-odata-v2-and-v4-client-for-java